# Different symbols for debugging arrays between renders React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

When evaluating an array of objects in the render method, console.log on Chrome prints an array of symbol *[ ]* and **array.map does not work**. After a re-render, the symbol is *[{...}]* and **map does work** as intended.

I want to know what these different symbols represent, as *the objects inside are completely unchanged* throughout the renders.

[Chrome console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eaBd.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Facts:

- `[]` means it's an empty array *AT the time of the `console.log`*
- `[{...}]` means the array has 1 object *AT the time of the `console.log`*

Your screenshot is only showing you *expanding* the array *after* it has been logged. Since it is the same array reference expanding *after* the mutation is showing you the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turns out I had a Promise inside another, so when I called .then() inside componentDidMount(), only one promise was resolved. As the first promise triggered a rerender but the second didn't (the reference was already there), it missed info.